# What is this insect species? It lives in damp places in a cocoon like structure and can protrude its head from both ends

Tags: species-identification

Lives in damp places and can protrude head from both directions, 1 cm long approximately
[image]

Comment: Yeah its a case bearing moth.. Thanks for responding! I was looking for it since long..